# Memcached for windows

Tags: java

How to install memcached on windows and use it? I want to configure tomcat for session mangement for java application (memcached session manager) like if there are two servers, if one goes down, the session data should not be lost. Can anyone tell me the steps for downloading and installing memcached ?

Comment: Do not use memcached alone for sessions. Use it as a caching layer if you must, but store session data in a database. http://dormando.livejournal.com/495593.html (**NB**: Dormando is one of the primary memcached authors.)

Comment: okay. But how to install memcached?

Comment: Download and compile it. There is no official Windows version, and most of the versions available online are badly out of date.

Answer (score 0):

As was previously said, using memcached for sessions is bad. If you're still looking for an installable binary for windows one of the Couchbase devs, Patrick Galbraith, maintains a distribution.  The downloads can be found linked from [his blog](http://blog.couchbase.com/blog/8)